# Antlr4.Runtime.dll Trimmed causing warning IL2104: Assembly 'Antlr4.Runtime' produced trim warnings

Tags: antlr4

C# project with .net 7.0 that is using Antlr4.Runtime.dll and publishing with flag: true
Causing warning:

```
warning IL2104: Assembly 'Antlr4.Runtime' produced trim warnings. For more information see https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/libraries
```

To repro the issue, create new project that is using ANTLR4 and publish it with true and the above trim flag. Observe the warning.

I guess the runtime library needs to be annotated as suggested in the above link.
I was trying to create a bug on this, but it asked me to start a question here first. So here I am.
Thanks,
Eugene